# RealmResult query again

Tags: android, realm

I use Realm for my Android Project.
In the `MainActivity` users can choose different `group` of `Contact`,the query `RealmResult` will be show in `RecyclerView`.When users choose another `group` ,it means that I have to query the 'Contact' again and reset the `Adapter`.
In my opinion, `RealmResult` can be query again (NOT IN THIS QUERY RESULT BUT IN THIS REALMOBJECT), and the `RealmResult` will be more `ReactiveX`.

Comment: Answered here: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2215